# Git pull fails with bad pack header error

Tags: git

git pull fails with following error

```
remote: Counting objects: 146, done.
remote: fatal: unable to create thread: Resource temporarily unavailable
error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: protocol error: bad pack header
```

Any Ideas how to pull successfully  ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Repack of Git repository fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826639/repack-of-git-repository-fails)

Comment: I get this with `git subtree add` too

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The lines beginning with `remote` are output from git running on the remote system.  The error:

```
fatal: unable to create thread: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

... strongly suggests that you've run out of memory on the server, which can happen if you have either:

1. A repository with lots of large files, which can cause re-packing to take a lot of memory.
2. Limited virtual memory - either in general, or just for that account due to the `ulimit` setting

A suggestion [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120113062341/http://oldwiki.joyent.com/shared:gittrouble) is to limit the amount of memory that packing may take by logging into the remote system (as the user that git runs as) and doing:

```
git config --global pack.windowMemory "100m"
git config --global pack.packSizeLimit "100m"
git config --global pack.threads "1"
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was receiving the same error as OP.  I tried implementing pack.windowMemory and pack.SizeLimit config items, but I was still receiving the error. 
When I added pack.threads "1" everything was resolved!

Comment: I started with great enthusiasm when I tried to switch from svn to git. But running from one obscure problem to problem whose fix is even more obscure, I am not sure how wise the decision was for the switch.

Comment: I had a problem with that I change property pack.SizeLimit instead of pack.packSizeLimit. This solved my problem. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: `git config --global pack.windowMemory "100m"` fixed my problem

Answer (score 12):

*Complementing the **@Mark Longair**'s answer*:

I had to run the following commands to fix this issue:

```sh
git config --global pack.windowMemory "100m"
git config --global pack.packSizeLimit "100m"
git config --global pack.threads "1" 
git config --global pack.deltaCacheSize "512m"
```

You can see more about these commands in the git documentation [`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-packdeltaCacheSize).

Comment: what are the default values of these parameters ?

Comment: According to the documentation page I mentioned above, the default value of `packSizeLimit` is *unlimited* and `pack.deltaCacheSize` is 256 MiB. `pack.threads` is not mentioned, but it's probably *auto detection* (same as zero).  But if you want to set them to default, you can simply delete them from the global config file.

Answer (score 2):

Warning: if you see this error with Git 2.19.1, this is expected, and documented in [`git-for-windows/git` issue 1839](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1839): "`git gc` crashes at 33% of counting objects" (which reports an APPCRASH both for `git gc`, but *also* for `git pull`), because of a mutex used in "git pack-objects", which was not correctly initialized and caused "`git repack`" to dump core on Windows.

As mentioned in the issue:

> It affects more than just `gc`. I hit a variant of it with `pull` too:
>
> ```
> $ git pull
> remote: Enumerating objects: 3548, done.
> error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
> fatremote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
> al: git uploadf-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
> atal: protocol error: bad pack header
> ```

This is fixed in Git 2.20 (Q4 2018).
See [commit 34204c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/34204c81668324480e1f34a09cce9c21fabf4b40), [commit 9308f45](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9308f45a9f1e3e107ba53a91d0f0c59342cb32bd), [commit ce498e0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce498e094e8db32fff358ecf7e4ad4951e6bebce) (16 Oct 2018) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 620b00e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/620b00e1671a8b4c1b00dbea8a0e81a657f28ce1), 30 Oct 2018)</sup>

> ### `pack-objects` (mingw): initialize `packing_data` mutex in the correct spot
>
> In [9ac3f0e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ac3f0e5b3e4cebe5bc9a24e3adef8b8e64fe692) (`pack-objects`: fix performance issues on packing large deltas, 2018-07-22, Git v2.19.0-rc1), a mutex was introduced that is used to guard the call to set the delta size. This commit even added code to initialize it, but at an incorrect spot: in `init_threaded_search()`, while the call to `oe_set_delta_size()` (and hence to `packing_data_lock()`) can happen in the call chain `check_object()` <- `get_object_details()` <- `prepare_pack()` <- `cmd_pack_objects()`, which is long before the `prepare_pack()` function calls `ll_find_deltas()` (which initializes the threaded search).
>
> Another tell-tale that the mutex was initialized in an incorrect spot is that the function to initialize it lives in builtin/, while the code that uses the mutex is defined in a `libgit.a` header file.

Comment: One can check the [size of those `object_entry`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61550028/6309)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this using following steps

Step 1. clone using lesser depth

git clone https://your_git_clone_url --depth 3

Step 2. Edit .git/config and add line for develop. This is required as after setting depth I was not able to switch remote branch other than master

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https:<your git clone url>
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
    fetch = +refs/heads/develop:refs/remotes/origin/develop  <<--- Add this line
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "develop"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/develop
```

Step 3: get fetch