# Pushing large commit to GitHub results in a fatal write error: Bad file descriptor

Tags: git, github, https

I'm using GitHub to manage my repository and I'm getting the following errors while attempting to push a large commit (1.5 GB).

```
error: pack-objects died of signal 9
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: write error: Bad file descriptor
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Are you using https/ssh/* for pushing? Is there any application on the other side (like gitlab)

Comment: As I first assumption it might be caused by the remote host

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git push "error: index-pack died of signal 9"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985124/git-push-error-index-pack-died-of-signal-9)

Comment: can you try pushing it segments and see if you still get a signal 9 error?

Comment: Is the disk full on the server?

Comment: @frlan: I'm using HTTPS and GitHub

Comment: Are you using proxy or transparent proxy?

Comment: @BorisBrodski: No, I'm not using a proxy of any kind...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Github drops the connection because of the large commit size. Consider this help page:

https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files

If you use SSH you will see something like this

> remote: warning: Large files detected.
>
> remote: error: File giant_file is 123.00 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100 MB

In this case your commit will be rejected. Using HTTPS there is currently no way to transmit the error message to your client.

Comment: I switched to SSH but I was getting the same errors. I just committed in several chunks and I was eventually able to get everything synced.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem with a git pack file. To get around it I repacked and specified the max size of the pack.

```
git repack --max-pack-size=100M -a -d
```

Answer (score 2):

This tip may apply to I was working with git trying to push to github on Bluehost but this could generically apply to a lot of hosting companies. Previous tips didn't work.
After getting such errors as

```
Counting objects: 3532, done.
Delta compression using up to 24 threads.
fatal: unable to create thread: Resource temporarily unavailable
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: write error: Bad file descriptor
```

This let me send git commits on the shared host. It must forbid additional threads.

```
git config --global pack.threads "1"
```

Related issues and solution here: [git push fatal: unable to create thread: Resource temporarily unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905257/git-push-fatal-unable-to-create-thread-resource-temporarily-unavailable/21953325)