# Unable to read file when pushing

Tags: ruby, git, github

I am trying to push work up to GitHub and I keep getting this error:

fatal: unable to read 71854be7eeb374bf85c2a3c24901887cf39d75d4

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

fatal: write error: Bad file descriptor

Is there any way to get Git to read that file, or delete the file completely?

Comment: possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561940/pushing-large-commit-to-github-results-in-a-fatal-write-error-bad-file-descript

Comment: could you show us the code?

Comment: **unable to read 71854be7eeb374bf85c2a3c24901887cf39d75d4** looks like your local files are having problems. Did you experience a crash recently or some file corruption ?

Comment: @LoicDachary Yes I did, I recently experienced some corrupt(empty) files and deleted them then this error happened