# Can't Determine The Source Of Git Push Fatal Error

Tags: git, push

I'm attempting to push a commit up to GitHub, however it receives the a fatal error, and verbose mode doesn't add any significant indicators to what the problem is

I've found plenty of online forums regarding fatal errors during pushing, however those all have more descriptive error messages than what I am getting

```
$ git push -v
Pushing to (Team Repos)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: write error: Bad file descriptor
error: failed to push some refs to '(Team Repos)'
```

The server isn't down, as I can access the Web GUI as well as perform fresh fetches/pulls

Comment: Look for server-side logs. You're getting the equivalent of the service person hanging up on you mid-call: there's no way to tell *why* that happened without more information from the *other* side.

Comment: What protocol are you using? ssh? https?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/20561940/6309 help?