# GIT: remote: fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 190135255 bytes)

Tags: git, malloc

trying to clone a big repository, I got:

```
remote: fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 190135255 bytes)
```

Saw that there is a possible configuration into `~/.gitconfig` or `.git/config` in the client, but as it seems to be the server which is enable to generate such a big file before passing it where can I configure the size of max malloc on the server?

### My system's server is

```
pi@domP3: ~$ git --version
git version 2.11.0
pi@domP3: ~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.4 (stretch)
Release:        9.4
Codename:       stretch
```

Comment: Is the server under your control? What's the server OS? What's git server software?

Comment: @phd thx, edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where can I configure the size of max malloc on the server?

Well, there is no magic in git; if you use git (probably over ssh) then the rule is pretty simple: there is

- a repository at the server side
- a local to the repository `.git/config`
- a global `~/.gitconfig`
- a system `/etc/gitconfig`.

The simplest (IMO) way to edit a config is to login to the server, `cd` to the repository and run `git config` to edit local config or `git config --global` to edit global config.

PS. The question is — if it's just Pi do you have enough virtual memory to increase malloc size in config?

Comment: Pi Memory: Have a swap file to make that possible yes, but your question is adecuate

Comment: which configuration do I have to add|set?

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26542281/7976758) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43934281/7976758). Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+remote%3A+fatal%3A+Out+of+memory

Comment: @Pipo: 190135255 = 181 MB, not 22 MB.

Comment: i figured it out ;-) can't edit my comment :-( as bytes where written with lowercase.... TLDR interpreted as bits first

Answer (score 0):

Working config for me was following on my bare repo:

```
/mnt/seagate_2_5i/gitRepo/documents.git/config


[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = true
        packedGitWindowSize = 512m
[pack]
        windowMemory = 512m
[http]
        postBuffer = 512m
```