# Git pull fails with "bad pack header"

Tags: git, git-pull

When I try to pull from remote server I get this error:

```
warning: no common commits
remote: Counting objects: 12358, done.
remote: warning: suboptimal pack - out of memory
error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
remote: Compressing objects:  92% (10914/11863)   fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
remote: fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 42679466 bytes)
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: protocol error: bad pack header
```

I tried to limit the memory being used on the remote server [per this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362709/git-pull-fails-with-bad-pack-header-error):

```
git config --global pack.windowMemory "100m"
git config --global pack.SizeLimit "100m"
git config --global pack.threads "1"
```

I'm not sure what the problem really is here.  Any other ideas?  TIA.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826639/repack-of-git-repository-fails

Answer (score 1):

Per the `Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 42679466 bytes)` message, my guess would be that your server is running out of RAM. Aren't you running it on some embedded/virtual/otherwise limited hardware?