# Does git support fetch the folder from server?

Tags: git, fetch, fatal-error

I run the git fetch command to get the update from server. It's OK for small update from other colleagues. But when someone pushed a big amount of data, it always failed, and says:"fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly, 1 Kib/s, fatal: early EOR fatal: index-pack failed".

So I am wondering if it is possible to fetch only a part of the update from colleagues, e.g. under some folder?

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are running into memory problems on the server? (See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826639).) Git can be quite memory hungry, especially with large files in the repository, and that does not play well with shared hosting machines, for example.

Comment: actually, we're using the repositoryhosting.com as our server. is there any issues with the server?

Comment: Ask their support about the maximum Git file/repository size they handle the amount of memory available to the Git process. Or you can point them directly to the problematic repository and ask them if the server can handle it.

Comment: I finally get it done via using some VPN. The fetch failed because of the poor network connections to the website, repositoryhosting.com. after enabling the VPN, I fetched it, although with some fail tries.