# Error when pulling warning: suboptimal pack - out of memory

Tags: git

I keep getting this error when trying to do a `git pull` or a `git gc`.

```
warning: suboptimal pack - out of memory 
Compressing objects: 100% (10955/10955), done.
fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 827101023 bytes)
error: failed to run repack
```

How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[This thread](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-gc-out-of-memory-td4005235.html) suggests

> run `git repack -adf --window=memory` on the repo where memory is escalated appropriately for your machine.

That is pretty much the same solution than for the SO question "[Repack of Git repository fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826639/repack-of-git-repository-fails)".

```
git repack -a -d --window-memory 10m --max-pack-size 20m
```

However, [Mark Longair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223092/mark-longair) will [warn you that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4829883/6309):

> Your solution has got you a working copy locally and remotely, but will cause problems again when the remote repository decides to repack itself again.

So configuring `pack.windowMemory` and `pack.packSizeLimit` is a much safer solution, as well as checking the config of `core.packedxxx` and `core.deltaxxx`.

For msysGit on Windows, this comment mentions:

```
git config --global pack.windowMemory 256m
```

> worked for me
>   (had have memory alloc error on 64 bit windows (Git-1.7.6-preview20110708.exe)

Answer (score -1):

Running

```
git repack -a -d --window-memory 10m --max-pack-size 20m
```

did not really solve my problem.

Removing the repository and then git cloning again solved the problem.

Comment: I am getting this when trying to pull just before pushing back to the remote.  Removing the repository and cloning again would undo my commits.