# After splitting a repo, new repos are many time larger

Tags: git

I recently split a git repo...

```
Project
    ProjectA
    ProjectB
    ProjectC
```

...into 3 repos...

```
ProjectA
ProjectB
ProjectC
```

...using the following guide:

[Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)

The size of the original repo (.git directory) was 3.7GB.  The project contains a lot of .psd files.

The problem is that one of the new repos (ProjectC) is now 5.9GB (.git folder).  Clearly there was some compression and/or diffing that was happening that is no longer happening.

I tried repacking and compressing using:

git repack -a -d --depth=250 --window=250

Based on information found on this page:

http://metalinguist.wordpress.com/2007/12/06/the-woes-of-git-gc-aggressive-and-how-git-deltas-work/

The size of the repo did not change.  Is there a way to get the repo to completely re-compress and re-diff everything?  Am I just doing something wrong?

The three original projects didn't share any files, so I doubt there was much diff gain from being able to diff across three projects vs one.

I'm not short of disk space, so this is largely just an educational exercise... plus it's driving me nuts.

Comment: Can you show the output of `git count-objects -v` in each new repository?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040083/error-when-pulling-warning-suboptimal-pack-out-of-memory/9041551#9041551 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882375/how-to-really-delete-a-git-branch-i-e-remove-all-of-its-objects-commits/2882485#2882485 help?

Answer (score 3):

OK, I'm going to answer my own question.  I just ran across this:

```
git gc --aggressive --prune=1day
```

I'd run `git gc --aggressive` on the repo with no real change in size, but adding the `--prune=1day` made all the difference.  The repo is now down to 1.9G.

Comment: It is ok, and even encouraged to answer one's own questions.

Comment: If you're talking about accepting the answer, I can't do that for another day.  Not sure why SO puts that restriction on people. I guess to keep them from gaming it.