# How to convert a downloaded repo into a git repo?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Due to some server issues resulting into the error: "aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.", I am not able to clone the repo. As per online research, I found that my server does not have enough RAM to process heavy memory usage. The repo size is 400mb.

Although, I have downloaded the code by clicking the latest commit > Browse code > Download as zip.

Is there a way to init this downloaded folder as git repo? So, that I can push the code?

Comment: No, you’ll be missing the history if you just downloaded a zip.

Answer (score 4):

You can use these commands

```
cd folder
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

Comment: I tried this earlier too. It initialises the folder as git but when I do a "git fetch". I see the same error again: remote: `Counting objects: 36548, done.
remote: warning: suboptimal pack - out of memory
error: pack-objects died of signal 937/17112)   
error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: protocol error: bad pack header
NipunR-Pax:helix.git Nipun$ git branch`

Comment: I need a way where I just need to add remote origin to the downloaded branch and just push my code. Server does not have enough memory to pull the code.

Comment: Can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040083/error-when-pulling-warning-suboptimal-pack-out-of-memory ?