# GIT GC Consumes Server Memory

Tags: git, git-gc

I am using Git on a virtual server hosted by dreamhost with 2GB memory. I run `git gc` every morning at 4AM and consistently for the past week, dreamhost process reboot send an email stating that due to the fact that I have consumed more than 2GB memory, they have rebooted my server to stop the process that is consuming the memory.

The repository size is 10GB in size. I have looked extensively before posting this, but is there a log file that Git creates that will allow me to see what file Git was 'touching' that caused the server forced restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no secret method of logging what was happening.  However, with a repository containing large objects, the `git repack` step may want to use huge amounts of memory, even with a small(ish) (i.e., default) `--window` and `--depth`.

The solution (besides avoiding silly restrictions on VM :-) ) is to use `git config` to set `pack.windowMemory` to some suitable limit.  See [Repack of Git repository fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826639/repack-of-git-repository-fails) as well.  (I have not run into this situation myself but this seems like the obvious answer, at least.)

Comment: tyvm torek, i appreciate your time