# git rev-list --all --objects fails with Out of memory, malloc failed

Tags: git, memory, malloc, git-rev-list

I am trying to run:

```
git rev-list --objects --all
```

using 32-bit cygwin, but it is failing with:

```
fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocated 805523547) bytes.
```

which corresponds to the size of a large blob that was committed early in the history of the repo.

By using the techniques in:

"[Repack of Git repository fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826639/repack-of-git-repository-fails)"

I was able to repack a clone of the repo using a 64 bit system and by rsyncing this back to the 32 bit system, I can now fetch the updates from the 64 bit repo into the 32 bit system, however, git rev-list --objects --all still fails on the 32 bit repo.

Are there any options that I can use to prevent git rev-list failing on this repo?

Comment: Maybe related to this? http://superuser.com/questions/537347/how-do-i-pull-big-repos-from-git-on-windows-without-getting-out-of-memory
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292903/git-on-windows-out-of-memory-malloc-failed

Comment: I had a look at that and tried repacking the source repo with the relevant options, but it didn't help. In the end, I think, the problem is the single large blob (git cat-file blob on that blob also failed) and the only way I am going to fix that permanently is to use filter-branch to remove it and its variants.

Comment: Yep, that worked for me. I did a git filter-branch with an --index-filter on the 64-bit repo on the last commit that had a reference to the big blobs, then added a graft to the 32-bit repo that referenced the rewritten history. With this graft in place, git rev-list --objects now completes without error.