# Git out of memory and then fatal - early EOF

Tags: git

Hi Im not sure if the errors are related but I said I should mention both in case they are.

Firstly as I was trying to push approx 1/1.5GB to my repo I was getting the following error...

```
Counting objects: 4876, done.
warning: suboptimal pack - out of memory
fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 156741292 bytes)
error: failed to push some refs to '/var/www/...'
```

I eventually resolved this by running these three commands in both the clone and repository..

```
git config pack.windowMemory "15m"
git config pack.SizeLimit "3m"
git config pack.threads "1"
```

Instead of it stopping I just got the suboptimal pack warning instead and it continued.

Now the issue is I am getting this error...

```
Compressing objects: 100% (4803/4803), done.
error: pack-objects died of signal 984.59 MiB | 6.89 MiB/s
remote: fatal: early EOF
```

I have been looking everywhere, I have tried 2 things so far but no joy...

```
git config http.postBuffer 52428800
git config --add core.compression -1
```

Both clone and repo on same server using ubuntu and git version 1.9.1

Comment: It's hard to read (because the 9 in "died of signal 9" is embedded right in the middle of "xxx MiB") but your server has run out of memory and the OOM killer killed `git pack-objects`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826639/repack-of-git-repository-fails (and also "OOM killer" articles here, on serverfault, and on the web).

Comment: thank you , having exhausted all my git options I took your advice and worked on this from a server point of view and the issue is resolved. I created a swap file (virtual memory)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a better answer for this from a git perspective, but having exhausted all my git options I took advice from torek and worked on this from a server point of view and the issue is resolved. I created a swap file (virtual memory) which solved the problem.