# "Command returned error:127" while executing git svn clone command

Tags: git

Objective:
To migrate from svn to gitlab with all the svn history.

Approach:
Used the following command:

```
git svn clone -r<intital revision number>:HEAD --authors-file=authors.txt <svn URL like http://svn/Trunk> <Destination Folder like C:/Project>
```

After almost 1 hour of fetching data from the svn, an error occurred:

```
ls-tree -z asdafsdfsdfsdfsdf ./xyz.java: command returned error: 127
```

Any suggestion to overcome the solution will be very helpful.

Comment: Well, what did you research, what did you find, what did you try?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826639/repack-of-git-repository-fails/4829883#4829883

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below command helped in resolving the issue:

```
git svn gc
```

After the above command, this command is triggered and the issue didn't occur.

```
git svn clone -r<intital revision number>:HEAD --authors-file=authors.txt <svn URL like http://svn/Trunk> <Destination Folder like C:/Project>
```